# Optimize sql script maxing out CPU

Tags: sql-server, database, query-optimization

I have an application that generates below SQL Statement.

```
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col1) SerialNo, col1, col2, col3, col4, 
col5, col6, col7, col8
from tableA where  (col3 like '%search1%' or col9 like '%search1%'or col10 
like '%search1%'or col5 like '%search1%' ) 
order by col5
```

It has recently become so slow( table has over 6 million records) and It's maxing out the CPU. Any idea on how this query can be optimized?
"search1" is any string entered by user split by space."

I have used performance monitor to analyze and i implemented all the recommendations which seemed to worsen it.

Comment: Too little info. Please provide: 1. table schema (including index definitions); 2. Execution plan for the current query; 3. Hardware specs

Comment: 6 million is a big number to run `LIKE` queries against

Comment: Your leading wildcard search ` LIKE '%...'` is not optimisable unless you can  implement something like this https://sqlperformance.com/2017/09/sql-performance/sql-server-trigram-wildcard-search or use full text search. Unfortunately, it is that simple

Comment: I have non clustered indexes created covering all the columns in the where clause and Individual indexes on each of the columns in the where clause

Comment: @gbn, thanks. I'm reading up on trigram to see if this will work for me.

Comment: double ended wildcards such as `col3 like '%search1%' ` **plus** multiples of those **& with OR**s as well, no way do a simple "optimize"

Answer (score 1):

Concat yours columns to make a search on this concat ;

```
where col3+col9+col10+col5 like '%search1%'
```

Make a subquery with your filter and then do your ROW_NUMBER on the lines of that recordset

```
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col1) SerialNo, col1, col2, col3, col4, 
col5, col6, col7, col8
from (select SerialNo,col1, col2, col3, col4, 
col5, col6, col7, col8 from tableA where  col3+col9+col10+col5 like '%search1%'
) as tfiltered
order by col5
```

Comment: That's a nice idea. I don't think, however, it's the separate `LIKE` on the four columns the DBMS must perform, that is causing the long execution time, but the fact that every single record must be read and compared. (Plus the two sorts on the result rows.) Your query may be a tad faster and it may be a tad slower. I don't think it will make a big change. But well, why not try it?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Due to the fact that some of those columns can be null, i also have to test for null before concatenating. The records are returned in same time as the original query.

Answer (score 1):

This is what happens:

1. Read the whole table sequentially record for record in order to find the desired records. (It would take longer, did the DBMS try to use an index for this.)
2. Sort the result rows by col1. This can take quite long when the result set is large.
3. Sort the result rows by col5. This can take quite long again.

I see the following ways to speed this up:

1. With multiple CPUs you can enforce parallel execution for the first step. This may help, but usually SQL Server itself would decide to run this in threads if multiple CPUs are available. I found this article on the subject: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4939/how-to-force-a-parallel-execution-plan-in-sql-server-2016/
2. Invest in hardware. Multiple CPUs for aforementioned point. More memory for sorting. Faster drives.
3. Restrict searches. So far a user can look for 'this thing' by entering 's thi'. If you restrict this to whole words, you could use full text search maybe. Or if you restricted this to certain key words, you could use lookup tables you build yourself. (E.g. rather then looking for '%shoes%', you'd have categories the table entries relate to and you'd look up category = 'shoes' instead.)

Comment: Great suggestions. I'm reviewing the article in the above link. My current execution plan however shows something on Parallelism. I will do a further review.

Comment: As for 2, I have made a request to increase the CPU cores from 8 to 16 to see if there will be any improvement and also increase the RAM. Your 3rd suggestion is very fantastic, just what I'm considering. Instead of allowing them type anything in the search box, force them to select  an option from a dropdown consisting of the 4 cols. This is however a major change that will require user re-orientation. But it's definitely on the table. I appreciate.